# Derivation of Moment of Inertia of a solid sphere

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, moment-of-inertia, rigid-body-dynamics

I was deriving the moment of inertia of a solid sphere taking a solid disc as an element opposed to a hollow sphere. During derivation I found a problem that the integrand was wrong as it should've been $cos^5(\theta)$ but I was getting $cos^4(\theta)$. Pleases suggest what is wrong?
[image]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You "$dv$" should involve a disc thickness of $dz= d(R \sin \theta) =R\cos\theta d\theta$. I think you just have $Rd\theta$.

Comment: why did you add cosθ to the thickness?

Comment: Because the vertical thickness of the disc  is $dz$ where $z=R \sin \theta$ is the vertical distance from the centre. You seem to have equated  the thickness to  the length $R d\theta$ of its sloping edge.  Anyway that's what jumped out at me when I looked at your work. I have not read the whole derivation.

Comment: so the length of the edge and thickness arent the same?

Comment: ohh i get it now because the mass isnt distributed only along the edges the thickness will be dz. i actually took the thickness of a ring

Answer (score -1):

Your error is in assigning the value $R\delta\theta$ as the thickness of the element, and you have also omitted to include the factor $\frac12$

The thickness should be $\delta y$ and since $y=R\sin\theta$, then $\delta y=R\cos\theta\delta\theta$ and that's where the missing $\cos\theta$ term has gone.

I hope this helps (the result follows).

Comment: actually our teacher took the thickness of the ring = Rdθ, while determining the moi of a hollow sphere so i took Rdθ the thickness of the disc. but when he used Rdθ the moi of hollow sphere was correct.

Comment: yes the **surface** element has thickness $R\delta\theta$ but that's not the same as the thickness of the volume element

Comment: yeah i made the same mistake while deriving com of a solid cone when our teacher told that the mass is distributed not only on the edges so thickness will be dz